# Variable number of days for time based workflows

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Is it possible to setup a time based workflow which depends on a variable number of days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula field that returns a date or date/time based on whatever variable calculations you'd like to use, then specify the time-based action as "0 hours after *Formula Field*". In short, any sort of calculation you can perform in a formula may be used to create a variable delay.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, works perfectly!